# Why does shapely intersection of two lines change behaviour when fiona module is imported?

Tags: python, intersection, shapely, fiona

I am having issues with calculating an intersection of two LineStrings using Shapely.  Such an intersection should return a point, yet my code returns a LineString.  I found a [simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22417842/how-do-i-find-the-intersection-of-two-line-segments) of an intersection of two lines, and it works as expected:

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString

line1 = LineString([(0,0), (2,2)])
line2 = LineString([(0,2), (2,0)])
print(line1.intersection(line2))
```

The resulting printout is:

```
POINT (1 1)
```

However, here is my code (with everything stripped out except for just enough to replicate the issue):

```
import fiona
from shapely.geometry import LineString

sch = {}
sch["properties"] = {}
sch["geometry"] = "LineString"
file = fiona.open("d:/tmp/test.gpkg", "w", driver="GPKG", schema=sch)

line1 = LineString([(0,0), (2,2)])
line2 = LineString([(0,2), (2,0)])
print(line1.intersection(line2))
```

The (incorrect) intersection result now becomes:

```
LINESTRING (2 2, 0 0)
```

So, something about fiona is changing the behavior of `intersection`.  If I comment out the call to `fiona.open` (but leave the `import fiona`) the result is an OSError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(line1.intersection(line2))
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\base.py", line 620, in intersection
    return geom_factory(self.impl['intersection'](self, other))
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\shapely\topology.py", line 65, in __call__
    self._validate(other, stop_prepared=True)
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\shapely\topology.py", line 19, in _validate
    if stop_prepared and not hasattr(ob, 'type'):
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\base.py", line 352, in type
    return self.geometryType()
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\base.py", line 348, in geometryType
    return geometry_type_name(self._geom)
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\base.py", line 70, in geometry_type_name
    return GEOMETRY_TYPES[lgeos.GEOSGeomTypeId(g)]
OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x0000000000000000
```

Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case this affects anyone else: I didn't identify the exact problem, but I believe it was somehow related to dependencies, in my case to an installation of OSGeo4W64.

I had OSGeoW64 on my machine so that I can use QGIS.  I am using Windows 7.  The example above was running using Python 3.7, which came with that OSGeo installation.  The fiona and shapely wheels (from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#fiona)) were installed using that version of Python.

I have a separate python standalone installation (3.6) on the same machine.  I uninstalled fiona and shapely from the 3.7, then I reinstalled them (different wheels for the different python version) for 3.6.  There was some hassling with GDAL, but with some help from [here](https://geoffboeing.com/2014/09/using-geopandas-windows/) I got it running.  (note that I am not using GeoPandas, which that link discusses - I am just using gdal, fiona, and shapely).

Now, the problem from my original post is solved: LineString intersection works properly whether or not fiona is involved.