# Error when viewing GeoDataFrame in GeoPandas: "OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x0000000000000000"

Tags: geopandas, error, fiona

When running the following script

```py
import fiona
import geopandas as gpd

data = gpd.read_file(r"C:\data.shp")
data.head()
```

I receive the following error

```
Access violation - no RTTI data!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1002, in __repr__ 
    show_dimensions=show_dimensions,
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1134, in to_string
    line_width=line_width,
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py", line 1053, in to_string
    string = string_formatter.to_string()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\string.py", line 25, in to_string
    text = self._get_string_representation()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\string.py", line 40, in _get_string_representation
    strcols = self._get_strcols()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\string.py", line 31, in _get_strcols
    strcols = self.fmt.get_strcols()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py", line 540, in get_strcols
    strcols = self._get_strcols_without_index()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py", line 804, in _get_strcols_without_index
    fmt_values = self.format_col(i)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py", line 825, in format_col
    leading_space=self.index,
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py", line 1240, in format_array
    return fmt_obj.get_result()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py", line 1271, in get_result
    fmt_values = self._format_strings()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py", line 1586, in _format_strings
    quoting=self.quoting,
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py", line 1240, in format_array
    return fmt_obj.get_result()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py", line 1271, in get_result
    fmt_values = self._format_strings()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py", line 1334, in _format_strings
    fmt_values.append(f" {_format(v)}")
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py", line 1314, in _format
    return str(formatter(x))
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\geopandas\array.py", line 1285, in <lambda>
    return lambda geom: shapely.wkt.dumps(geom, rounding_precision=precision)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\shapely\wkt.py", line 62, in dumps
    return geos.WKTWriter(geos.lgeos, trim=trim, **kw).write(ob)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\shapely\geos.py", line 402, in write
    text = string_at(result)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 505, in string_at
    return _string_at(ptr, size)
OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x0000000000000000
```

What is going on here?

Comment: Please check these: (1) https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/306583/29431   (2)  https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/333508/29431

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error that you caught. What I had to do was :

1 - reinstall QGIS, in my case, I installed the 3.22.6 that right now is the long term release;

2 - After the installation of QGIS, I also had to reinstall geopandas and it's dependencies in the OsGeo4W Shell. There is this really simple video in [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H1A5mZDoXYg) that teaches you how to install the packages without errors.

After this my geometries loaded just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, solved by downgrading Shapely from 1.8.5 to version 1.6.0

```
pip install shapely==1.6.0
```

...with Python 3.9, GDAL 3.4.3, Fiona 1.8.21, Geopandas 0.10.2 in a Conda environment (and finally I used PostGIS to do what I wanted to do)...